# Wifi Adapter Unclaimed RTL8723BE

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

Hey Guys New to Ubuntu so Be kind to me.
I Have been having Slow speed constant Disconnecting for while. I did nothing as i was told Ubuntu had some issues. But Now i get This [no wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqp2N.jpg)

so i executed *sudo lshw -c Network I got wificard as Unclaimed.
[Unclaimed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqp2N.jpg)

what to do next as tried all methods on Google to install drivers and Disabled secure boot.

Comment: This means that there is no driver loaded.  Either nowhere is no driver for this device available, or a driver is available but its firmware image is missing.  Look at the systemd journal or dmesg for details.

Comment: this what i got when starting driver:Apr 11 18:02:57 Lenovo-Flex-2-14D kernel: ---[ end trace 5c8fa3687516466b ]---
Apr 11 18:02:57 Lenovo-Flex-2-14D kernel: rtl_pci: Can't register mac80211 hw.

Comment: Please add the relevant context of the log to the question.

Comment: from i understand mac80211 in not loading

Comment: well Reverting back to old kernel did the trick thanks @rexkogitans